# Data gets reset before sent

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Well, first start of with the code

JavaScript:

```
function keyevent(e) // submit key
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13) // 13 = enter key
    { 
        $(this).val("");
    }
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#send').click(function() {
         $('.message').val("");
     });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="message" class="message" onKeyDown="javascript:keyevent(event);" />
<button name="send" id="send" onclick="refresh();" />Send</button>
```

Then I also have a if (isset($_POST['send')) higher up on my page. But when I then see the message I sent, the messagebox is empty because the value of message didn't exist.

So my question is, how do I "delay" the remove action? I have tried with delay()

Comment: Won't the text in the input field disappear upon refreshing the page?

Comment: So you clear the message when enter is hit in the message textbox, but you actually do not want to clear the message, at least not until after something else (the submission of the form?) occurs?? Why are you clearing it in the first place?

Comment: I work on a chatsystem and the page can't reload every single time you write anything. So the page won't reload as PHP usally do. But then the text from the input won't disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Educated guess, what you need is this.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.message').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });

  $('#send').click(function() {
    refresh();
    $('.message').val('');
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="message" class="message" />
<button name="send" id="send">Send</button>
```